# Old 8 bit retro video emulation - sprite drawing

Tags: video, graphics, hardware, sprite

I'm trying to understand how sprites are drawn onto scanlines of for example the VDP 9929A graphics chip, for emulation.

There is the limit of 4 sprites per scanline, does that mean i cannot have more than four sprites with the same y coordinate?

If I cascade them to say draw 32 sprites on each line below one another and one pixel to the right of each other so that they are overlapping each other, this would result in the centre of about 16 sprites being drawn on the same line. 
Would they still be drawn correctly as it is not the scanline relating starting y coord.
Hope I'm making sense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> There can be no more than 4 sprites on a single scanline; any additional sprites' horizontal pixels are dropped. Sprites with a higher priority are drawn first.

In other words, for each line, the chip will draw the 4 sprites with the highest priority that *exist* on the line, not *start* on the line.

```
1111        3333        5555
1111  2222  3333  4444  5555  6666
1111  2222  3333  4444  5555  6666
1111  2222  3333  4444  5555  6666
      2222        4444        6666
```

....where 1 is the highest prio, would for scan line 1 draw sprite 1,3,5, for scan line 2-4 draw 1,2,3,4, for scanline 5 draw 2,4,6.

```
1111        3333        5555
1111  2222  3333  4444  
1111  2222  3333  4444  
1111  2222  3333  4444  
      2222        4444        6666
```